# UEFI Linux Install on Acer Aspire ES1-111M

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

After installing ubuntu when ever I restart the computer it goes to the screen that gives me options to `Try Ubuntu` or `Install Ubuntu`. What do I do here? I've been through the installation process multiple times. If I take out boot drive I get `No bootable device`.

Comment: Your install media should only be the 'boot' drive during installation; once you've installed you should eject your install-media and the bootable drive should be the hdd/sdd/device you installed ubuntu on to. We can only assume it was a hdd or sdd as it is for most, and you've told us nothing else. Getting the hdd/sdd to boot is a BIOS issue so look for options there

Comment: what computer do you have? are you installing legacy or efi mode?

Comment: Do you have two hard drives  or any two storage  connected via the same cable?

Comment: My computer is an acer es1. I was looking into this and it seems to be a problem with acer, here is a link: http://william.shallum.net/random-notes/uefi-linux-install-on-acer-aspire-es1-111m. How do I know which esp file to trust?

Comment: shimx64.efi is the signed bootloader if you want secure boot on. grubx64.efi is the unsigned bootloader if you want secure boot off.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use UEFI and secure boot
2. Set supervisor passcode and select shimx64.efi as trusted if you want secure boot on, select grubx64.efi if you want secure off.